# Is there a better way to do this? Reusing the same loop in multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

These 3 functions use the same loop separately.

Should I remove the loops from each function and put them in one large loop? Is there some other better way?

```
    function createArrayOfNames(catsArray) {
        var catNames = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<catsArrayLength; i++) {
            catNames.push(cats[i].name);
        }
        return catNames;
    }

    //
    function createArrayOfListElements(listElement, catNames) {
        for(i = 0; i<catsArrayLength; i++) {
            var listElements = [];
            var listElement = listElement;
            listElement.innerHTML = catNames[i]
            listElements.append(listElement);
        }
        return listElements;
    }

    //Adds cat names to the catList unordered list (inside the catListContainer div)
    function addCatListToView(listElements, catNames) {
        for(i = 0; i<catsArrayLength; i++) {
            getElementById('allCats').append(listElements[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your methods do different things. How would combining them help? Also, `createArrayOfListElements` will only return a list with 1 element. And what's with `var listElement = listElement;`?

Comment: _3 functions use the same loop separately._ I don't see any likeness, except `for` construct usage.

Comment: Looks like there's some funky design going on. Why is `catsArrayLength` being referenced as a shared variable? What is the relationship between that, `cats` and `listElements`? You've given an incomplete example, so any suggestion has to make too many assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, creating an iterating function would be a nice way to make your code more readable.

```
function iterateCats(callback) {
    for(i = 0; i<catsArrayLength; i++) {
        callback(i);
    }
}
```

But as [@squint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559467/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-this-reusing-the-same-loop-in-multiple-functions/34559494#comment56862472_34559494) mentioned, if you don't mind making your `catsArray` available to all your functions, using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the standard and quicker way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, but no. `forEach` is not the same, first it skips over undefined values.

Comment: That's a good thing, considering `cats[i].name`. And it doesn't skip `undefined` values. It skips holes in the Array. If he has a sparse array, there's probably something wrong anyway.

Comment: Mmh yea, good point. Still, knowing how to make your own `forEach`-like function is definitely useful, if only for encapsulation. But you're right that for this case, `forEach` does the job better.

Comment: I agree. Sure doesn't hurt to know these basic things. There's some funkiness to the code in the question though. Would be better if he gave a more complete picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to clean up the code a little. Also, be careful, you were resetting `var listElements = [];` on each iteration.

```
function createArrayOfNames(catsArray) {
    return catsArray.map(function (c) {
        return c.name
    });
}

function createArrayOfListElements(catNames) {

    var listElements = [];

    catNames.forEach(function(name) {
        var listElement = new listElement();
        listElement.innerHTML = name;
        listElements.append(listElement);
    });

    return listElements;
}

function addCatListToView(listElements) {

    var catElements = getElementById('allCats');

    listElements.forEach(function(element) {
        catElements.append(element);
    };
}
```